# How to show info wndow on marker in here map SDK 3.6

Tags: android, here-api

old version have method showInfoBubble() but deprecated in sdk 3.6 of here map, now how to show info on marker.

Here are the code.

```
MapMarker marker = new MapMarker();
            GeoCoordinate geoCoordinate = new GeoCoordinate(c.getLat(), c.getLng());
            marker.setCoordinate(geoCoordinate);
            marker.setTitle(c.getTicket());
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            stringBuilder.append("Name : " + (TextUtils.isEmpty(c.getName()) ? "N/A" : c.getName().trim()) + "\n");
            stringBuilder.append("Address : " + (TextUtils.isEmpty(c.getStreetAddress()) ? "N/A" : c.getStreetAddress().trim()) + "\n");
            stringBuilder.append("Telephone : " + (TextUtils.isEmpty(c.getTelephone()) ? "N/A" : c.getTelephone().trim()));
            marker.setDescription(stringBuilder.toString());

            mMap.addMapObject(marker);
```

MapOverlay mapOverlay = new MapOverlay(view, marker.getCoordinate());

```
             mMapOverlay.put(c.getId(), mapOverlay);
```

Comment: What you had done so far ? Please paste code while asking on SOF

Comment: I inflated the map overlay view on the marker location, but this hides the marker icon, I just wanted info show like google map marker 's info window

Comment: Make it good practise to post your effected code while asking over to SOF. Nobody can  help you without knowing your code piece. And no one is here to code for you.  How i will understand where r u doing mistake ? Paste your code and then discuss..

Comment: I added the code please check

Comment: marker.showInfoBubble(); is not working in sdk3.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The infoBubble in the HEREMobileSDK was deprecated for quite a long time already. In the deprecation message it was suggested to switch over to MapOverlay: https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/api_reference_java/com/here/android/mpa/mapping/MapOverlay.html

So, what does this mean: 
Instead of showing a quite static/predefined infobubble from the HERE mSDK, you should use MapOverlay, that let you add complete View objects (Android Views) as an overlay to a pinned position on the map.

In your case, you might want to listen for the marker click event, and if this happens, then you add a Android View that looks how you want it as a MapOverlay to the map. 
The Map overlay is constructed like this: MapOverlay (View view, GeoCoordinate coordinate) and will be pinned to that given position.

Keep a reference to the MapOverlay, since you need to handle on your own when it should appear and disappear.

Comment: I did the same but MapOverlay hides the marker icon. I wanted to show like google map. How's that possible?

Comment: As said, you design a Android View of your choice, that you will position with the MapOverlay at a static position on the map. So design a View that looks like a infobubble and has al the information and fields you want, and push it as a MapOverlay to the coordinates of the marker. To prevent overlapping, I'd suggest setting in the View a marking to overcome this, and also set the View anchor point to bottmn - this probably needs some graphical tweaking till it fits your setup. Good luck.