# Show HERE Maps Marker Title

Tags: android, here-api

I am attempting to show the title of a map marker using Here Maps.

According to this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48200066/how-to-show-info-wndow-on-marker-in-here-map-sdk-3-6), the `showInfoBubble()` is deprecated. And the link it contains goes 404.

However, the [official documentation](https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-starter/api_reference_java/com/here/android/mpa/mapping/MapMarker.html#showInfoBubble--) does **not** show it as deprecated.

My map will always just show two or less locations. And I wanted to show the info bubble with the title. However, `showInfoBubble()` isn't a method of the MapMarker class despite being shown as one.

I have searched the [official GitHub](https://github.com/heremaps/here-android-sdk-examples) for examples, however I cannot find anything on showing the title.

**Has anyone figured this out?** Or can you point me to an example or the correct documentation?

```
    private void addMarkerAtPlace(GeoCoordinate marker, String title, String description, Image icon) {
            MapMarker mapMarker = new MapMarker();
            mapMarker.setIcon(icon);
            mapMarker.setCoordinate(new GeoCoordinate(marker));
            mapMarker.setTitle(title);
            mapMarker.setDescription(description);

            m_map.addMapObject(mapMarker);
            m_mapObjectList.add(mapMarker);

      //Show Title can only be shown after being added to the map
      //however this doesn't work!!!
            mapMarker.showInfoBubble();

        }
```

Comment: A comment about the deprecation: You refer to the Starter SDK version 3.x, but the linked SO question was about the Premium SDK. Two different products at the moment. Deprecation seems to be the case only for the Premium edition (where MapOverlays have been introduced, what's also not available in Starter as far as I can see).

Answer (score 0):

Summary: A comment about the deprecation: You refer to the Starter SDK version 3.x, but the linked SO question was about the Premium SDK. Two different products at the moment. Deprecation seems to be the case only for the Premium edition (where MapOverlays have been introduced, what's also not available in Starter as far as I can see). 
See current overview for the SDKs over here: https://developer.here.com/products/here-sdk